# how to have delimeter/separate between <f:selectItems> for <p:selectOneMenu>

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I need to have a separator/delimiter between `<f:selectItems>` for `<p:selectOneMenu>` this is JSF2 + Primeface3 web application. Please find the code below:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="select_city" value="#{BsnsDshbrdBen.venue.city}"
  rendered="#{!BsnsDshbrdBen.venue.isOnlineOffer}" onchange="geoEncodeForStrTab();" style="width: 370px" >
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select city" itemValue="CITY_ALL" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{CtyBen.citiesMap}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Any helps is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by you need a separator between `<f:selectItems>`? What is the type of `BsnsDshbrdBen.venue.city` and what would you like to save there? And what does `CtyBen.citiesMap` contain?

Answer (score -1):

Try with this:

```css
.ui-selectonemenu-list-item {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this and then how to do the same in case of <p:selectManyMenu> and <f:selectItems>?

Comment: Just look at the class they're using at client side. Then add a `border-bottom`.

Comment: Tried but doesnt work. Here is the code:
                                <p:selectManyMenu
                                   id="venue"
                                   value="#{PstOfrBen.selectedVenues}"
                                   required="true"
                                    style="width: 285px;height: 200px">
                                    <f:selectItems value="#{BsnsDshbrdBen.business.venues}" var="venue" itemLabel="#{venue.venueAsDisplayString}" itemValue="#{venue.seoURL}" />
                                </p:selectManyMenu>

Comment: This question is about `<p:selectOneMenu>`. Just adapt or edit it, or start a different thread.